# Unity: How to make input field respond to only double taps in Android?

Tags: unity, c#

I am using Unity in my Android project. There are input fields in my app. As soon as I click on the field the keyboard pops up. I want the keyboard to only show up when there is a double-tap on the field. But I am not able to get it to work and I have tried several ways.

**Requirement 1:** Single tap shouldn't open keyboard

**Requirement 2:** Double tap should open keyboard

I tried `OnPointerClick` method of `IPointerClickHandler` but this doesn't seem to work. I used this code in one of the scripts attached to input field with `IPointerClickHandler`.

```
public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (eventData.clickCount == 2)
    {
        Debug.Log("UNITY - Double click");
    }
    else if (eventData.clickCount == 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("UNITY - Single click");
    }
}
```

Then there is also the question of how to hide the keyboard or prevent it from opening on single tap. This also I am not able to solve. I started with clicking the `Hide Soft Keyboard` in control setting of `InputField` in Unity editor. But surprisingly this starts opening a keyboard which has mobile input.

Can someone help? I have been stuck on this for some time I can't seem to be getting anywhere.